# facing issue with passport js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I am new to node js and I am trying to make an example for authorization with **google passport** below is my code:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID        : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      clientSecret    : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      callbackURL     : "http://localhost/google/login",
      passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    return done(); //this is the issue, I am confused with it's use
  }
));

app.get('/failed', function (req, res) {
  res.send('failed login')
});

app.get('/final', function (req, res) {
  res.send('finally google auth has done')
});

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/google/login',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/failed' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/final');
  });

app.listen('80', () => {
  console.log('server is running')
})
```

Finally, My goal is to successful login with google without checking the value from DB as I am just learning it.

> node index.js
>
> and then i am opening url: http://localhost/auth/google

my program should run `get /final` after login with google credential but getting an error that `TypeError: done is not a function`

I am not getting the use of `done()` and how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `passReqToCallback : true`, you need to change the arguments of the callback function. `req` needs to be passed too as the first argument of the callback function.

your callback functions argument should be `(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)`

And that is why you are getting the error :

> done is not a function

Try this :

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID        : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      clientSecret    : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      callbackURL     : "http://localhost/google/login",
      passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    return done(); // it will work now
  }
));
```